# scikit-learn ExtraTreesClassifier - Why is the pickle file so huge? (Several GB)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, pickle, joblib

Using python + scikit-learn, I fit an "Extremely Randomized Trees" classifier (ExtraTreesClassifier) to a ~ 900K sample array of 100 features (real-valued float64). I then tried to pickle it.

I instantiated the classsifier with:

> cls = ExtraTreesClassifier(n_estimators=10, random_state=0,
>   n_jobs=-1)

After fitting, I tried two ways of saving:

> ```
> pickle.dump(cls, open(classifier_file, "wb"))
> ```

and, with joblib:

> ```
> from sklearn.externals import joblib
> joblib.dump(cls, classifier_file)
> ```

In the regular pickle, it takes up 4+ gigabytes of space!
In the joblib version, it takes up about 1.5 gigabytes of space.

Is it inherently storing some of the raw input data fit or predicted with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single "Extremely Randomized Tree" may be expected to grow with the size of the input data as it creates a decision tree that splits the data into leaf nodes with a small number of observations (e.g. either hitting the parameterized limit--by default this is `min_samples_split=2` or `pure` and containing a single class).

Data with a lot of highly predictive features will have pure nodes with a larger number of observations and so take up less space. The size of the storage should also be roughly proportional to the number of estimators.

Comment: Hey thank you that clarifies it and is very informative on how it works a bit under the hood.